# Configuring release notes on ASP.NET MVC & Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, versioning, viewbag

I'm trying to set up our build number and release notes on ASP.NET MVC with Razor--it seems like there is some functionality built in, because this is already in the main layout page in the header:

`<a href="@ViewBag.VersionLink">Build: @ViewBag.VersionInfo</a>`

We are on build 145 now, however, it always says `Build: 1.0.0.0` and the link goes to `App_Readme/Build1.0.0.0.txt` which just spits this out:

```
Hi, 
This is build 1.0.0.0
Thanks
```

I can not figure out where to update the build info. I've tried to backtrace it but it hasn't lead anywhere, and [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc%20razor%20build%20implementation) [has](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc%20razor%20configure%20release%20notes) [not](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc%20razor%20release%20notes%20how%20set%20up) [turned](https://www.google.com/search?q=razor%20release%20notes%20VersionLink) [up](https://www.google.com/search?q=razor%20release%20notes%20VersionLink%20VersionInfo) [much](https://www.google.com/search?q=razor%20release%20notes%20viewbag) that is useful.

How can I configure the release notes or set up the build versioning? I'll even accept an answer that points me to a good online resource that will help me out.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized that. Fixed.

Comment: what are you trying to get? the version of asp.net mvc or build version of your application?

Comment: @ElYusubov; my application. I would like to update the version number with each build, and potentially even implement release notes.

Comment: do you pass that information in controller to your view?

Comment: @EIYusubov; no. I don't even know what that means, let alone how to do it. :) What information should I pass to my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short:** There is no black magic that will know the applications build or release version  in asp.net mvc. Thus, this information needs to be passed from your controller to the View.

You may use a strongly typed viewmodel or `TempData` to pass that information to the ASP.NET MVC view.

Here you are some references to look - [Intro to ASP.NET MVC 3 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3).

**Edit:** If you would like to use `ViewBag` then this video-tutorial is very handy one to consider: - [**ViewBag: Introduction to MVC - Course**](http://mrbool.com/viewbag-introduction-to-mvc-course-asp-net-4-and-visual-studio-2010-part-36/22394)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would have liked something more specific, but perhaps my question was not specific enough in the first place.